# Convert binary tree to a list with level order in Python

Tags: python, list, binary-tree, breadth-first-search

I have not found any related questions yet.

So the problem is: given an incomplete binary tree, say the root of the tree, how can I convert it into a list in level order in Python such that the empty nodes (missing nodes in that level) are represented as "None" in the list.

For example, I have this tree:

```
     1
   /   \
 4      0.52
/ \      / \
   2.5
```

I want to get the following list:

```
[1, 4, 0.52, None, 2.5, None, None]
```

by using some function like:

```
list = toList(root)
```

In addition, I have tree structured like this:

```
class TreeNode:

def __init__(self, value, isLeaf):

    self.left = None
    self.right = None
    self.value = value
    self.isLeaf = isLeaf
```

And borrow the solution from another post (to a list without 'None' taken place):

```
def toList(root):
    node_list = []
    thislevel = [root]
    while thislevel:
        nextlevel = list()
        
        for n in thislevel:
            # print(n.value)
            node_list.append(n.value)

            if n.left: 
                nextlevel.append(n.left)
            if n.right: 
                nextlevel.append(n.right)
        # print
        thislevel = nextlevel
    return node_list

my_list = toList(root)
print(my_list)
```

This gives the following so far:

```
[1, 4, 0.52, 2.5]
```

I am stuck here, don't know how to properly insert 'None' into the list...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already attempted to create the list without the 'None's? i.e. do you have the code working for lever order without accounting for missing nodes? If not, try that first and post your attempt.

Comment: Yes, please see the updated post

Comment: Why doesn't the list have `None` values for the children of the `2.5` node? Is the 2.5 node somehow different than the `0.52` which does contribute `None` to the final list?

Comment: What is the exact value of `root`?, It's too abstract.

Comment: I'm thinking that it only outputs until the height of the tree. since `2.5` is at the bottom of the tree, it does not have any 'None's attached to it. Whereas `0.52`  is in the middle of the tree so we should consider both of its children are missing

Comment: the value of the root in the above example is `1`.  `root` just the first pointer to the rest of the tree here so I don't want to make this question over-complicated by adding the part of how the tree was composed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typically make a breadth-first iteration of a graph by using a `queue`. This is a first-in, first-out data structure. You start by adding the root to the queue, and then while the queue has items in it, you pop out the oldest one, add it to the results and the push its children into the queue. If you are doing this for anything other than small input, python’s [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is more efficient than the list used here:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, value, isLeaf):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.value = value
        self.isLeaf = isLeaf

        
def breadth_first(t):
    q = [t]
    while q:
        current = q.pop(0)
        yield current.value if current else None
        if current and not current.isLeaf:
            q.extend([current.left, current.right])
        
            
t = TreeNode(1, False)
t.left = TreeNode(4, False)
t.right = TreeNode(0.52, False)
t.left.right = TreeNode(0.2

list(breadth_first(t))
# [1, 4, 0.52, None, 0.25, None, None]
```

Comment: Thanks @BowlOfRed. You are of course correct. Attributing my error to weekend brain syndrome. Edited.